# Static vs. function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain why this is correct:

```
class Solution{
  static main() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
  }  
}
```

And why is this **not** correct?

```
class Solution{
  function main() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
  }  
}
```

I thought you always have to define a function with the **function** keyword.

Comment: That's just how the syntax works with `class`. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) Also, arrow functions do not need the `function` keyword either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static class methods are not called on *instances* of the class, but on the class itself. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) explains that quite well. As for the second part, that's just how the `class` syntax works.

Comment: All right, thank you. Will accept when it's allowed in a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

`class` is syntax sugar for this anyway:

```
function Solution() {}

Solution.main = function () { ... };
```

When they created the `class` syntactic sugar to make it *easier* to write this kind of structure, they also decided to omit the requirement to type `function`, since it's clear that `main() { ... }` is a function definition in this context even without the `function` keyword. There's nothing an additional "`function`" would add to the meaning here, so why type it?

Comment: Hmm, yeah that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Just a follow up question, if you don't mind: I tried to omit `function`, so that it is the same structure as in the original question, but only `...main() {...`, but it still gives me an error - with other words, `static` *seems to be required*. I am interested in *why* `static` is required in this context?

Comment: I stated it in the OP. The second example I gave is not correct. I am interested in knowing why I have to use the keyword `static` within a class to define a function.

If I do as in the second example from the OP, I get this error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: Well, again, because the ECMAScript specification deems it unnecessary and in fact illegal to add a `function` keyword there. You either leave it out completely to define a regular instance method, or you add the optional keyword `static` to define a class method. In neither case is `function` a legal keyword there.